# UIKit ) How to update textarea value

Tags: javascript, uikit

When use UIKit2.4, UIKit auto create editor.

I want to update editor's input value by javascript.

My Code is below.

```
<textarea id="body" data-uk-htmleditor="{markdown:true}">

  window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('body').value = "foo";
  };
```

this code change textarea's value. but,

editor's inner text (=shown value) is no change! Why?

How should I do? Please.

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you can try to add the  '/textarea' to complete the html

Answer (score 0):

resolve this.

UIKit Editor depend on codemirror.

```
    var editor = $('.CodeMirror')[0].CodeMirror;
    var doc = editor.getDoc();
    var cursor = doc.getCursor();
    doc.replaceRange(text, cursor);
```